# iPhone - Will this leak?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a setter like this:

```
- (UIImagePickerController *) foto {

    if (_foto == nil) { 
        _foto = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        _foto.delegate = self;
    }
    return _foto;
}
```

it is declared like

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImagePickerController *foto;
```

with

```
@synthesize foto = _foto;
```

on my dealloc I have

```
[_foto release];
```

At some point in my code I want to do this

```
self.foto = nil;
```

but something in my soul says the object assigned to self.foto previously will leak, because it was alloc on the setter... how do I make it right?

thanks.

Comment: _foto = self; makes no sense to me? I dont get that. (I would never use it but maybe you know lots more than me).

Comment: sorry, it was a typo. The correct is _foto.delegate = self...

Comment: ahh thanks. I was thinking was super strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: No, that should be fine. As long as you don't assign something else to _foto before you release, it should work.

Yup. You create an object, then loose the pointer to it. If you throw an autorelease on the init line, that will fix it. You could also use ARC.

The init line doesn't actually do anything... You assign the pointer to an object you create, then assign it to something else.

Comment: so, what your idea is to put an autorelease on the setter and remove the [_foto release] from the dealloc?   (I cannot use ARC in this project)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a leak there. When you assign to self.foto like this:`self.foto = nil;`, it will release the former one automatically. If you assign it by this way: `_foto = nil;`, you need to release it manually before the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that works, and will not leak. When you set the value of `_foto`, its retain count is 1 (because you called `alloc`). As long as you release it (which you've said you do) in `dealloc`, you should be fine, as the retain count will go back to 0. UNLESS your setter is ALSO written by you, and written improperly. It needs to explicitly release the old value, if it's not `nil`. Something like this:

```
- (void)setFoto:(UIImagePickerController*)foto {
     if (_foto) {
          [_foto release];
          _foto = nil;
     }
     if (foto)
          _foto = [foto retain];
}
```

Comment: as yibuyiqu says, if you've declared a property with `retain`, then it will automatically release the old value. Voila, no leak!

Comment: Actually, you should be careful -- if you just write `[_foto release]` in `dealloc`, and you haven't called your getter yet, you'll get a crash. Check that the pointer isn't nil, first: `if (_foto) [_foto release];`

Comment: sending a release message (or any message) to a nil pointer will not crash.  It will ignore the message.

Comment: Really? Good to know! That will save me time.